# Which in turns improve/improves longevity

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

This is a subject-verb agreement particularly within a relative clause. Let's say you were asked if you like holidays.

> Question: do you like holidays?
>
> Answer: Yes, I do. Because it's a great way to de-stress, which in turn **improve/improves** longevity.

Is it **improve** or **improves**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with your question because it mixes singulars and plurals.

What you ask is:

> Do you like holidays?

**Holidays** is plural.

What you answer is:

> Yes, I do. Because **it's** a great way....

**It's** is singular.

To be consistent, the answer should have been:

> Yes, I do. Because **they're** a great way.

Alternatively, you might have asked **do you like going on holiday**, which could be followed by **it's**.

So you can choose either **they (the holidays) improve**

or

**It's (going on holiday) improves.**

Comment: Yes, I missed that, oh man. Anyway, you have edited my ''which in turns'' to ''which in turn''. To be clear, is it possible to say **which in turns**?

Comment: @JohnArvin The expression *which in turn* does not take an **s**.  You could add an **s** only if you meant something completely different, such as: *...which, in turns to the left and the right, they succeeded in doing.*